# Add Value in rectangle in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have created [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/XvlXGrsStKQ61TEMZAA2?p=preview) for detail view.

I want to add hovered chart point in rectangle red box.

Help needed.

```
Thanks in advance.
```

Comment: there's three values on hover -> which one?

Comment: @RobyRodriguez All value i need to display in rectangle

Answer (score 1):

Well in your code you are appending the text with in the `rect` DOM.
That is the reason why you don't see the text.

The solution would be 
Step 1:

Create the Text (In our case 3 Text )

```
var textG = mouseG.append('text')
                .attr('y',height+25)
                .attr('font-family',"sans-serif")
                .attr('font-size',"8")
                .attr('fill', 'Black')
                .style("text-anchor", "middle")
var textB = mouseG.append('text')
                .attr('y',height+15)
                .attr('font-family',"sans-serif")
                .attr('font-size',"8")
                .attr('fill', 'Black')
                .style("text-anchor", "middle")
var textR = mouseG.append('text')
                .attr('y',height + 8)
                .attr('font-family',"sans-serif")
                .attr('font-size',"8")
                .attr('fill', 'Black')
                .style("text-anchor", "middle")
```

Step 2:

On mouse out make the opacity 0.

```
    d3.select("#test")
      .style("opacity", "0");
    textG
      .style("opacity", "0");
    textB
      .style("opacity", "0");
    textR
      .style("opacity", "0");
```

Since you don't want to see the text as mouse is out.

Step 3:

On mouse over set the text and x of the text DOM

```
        if (i ==2){
          textG.text(y.invert(pos.y).toFixed(2))
                  .attr('x',mouse[0])
        } 
        if (i ==1){
          textB.text(y.invert(pos.y).toFixed(2))
                  .attr('x',mouse[0])
        } 
        if (i ==0){
          textR.text(y.invert(pos.y).toFixed(2))
                  .attr('x',mouse[0])
        }
```

working code [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/iJZrs9jPuQzgvqH7NvzQ?p=preview)